# Laravel session is not taking long as expected

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a Laravel ( SSR WEBSITE ) + Vue.js application, and for using information about the user I store it in sessions and i access it and create it with Vue.js.

The problem is that I put this in session.php file from Laravel to lifetime be 1 month

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 43804),

    'expire_on_close' => false,
```

and every day my session is expiring why? This is the functions that i create on UserController.php

```
 public function storeUserSession(Request $request) {

        $userObjDataTemp = $request->input('userObjData');
        $request->session()->put('userObjData', $userObjDataTemp);
        $response['success'] = 1;
        $response['message'] = 'Sessão iniciada';
        return $response;

    }

    public function getUserSession(Request $request) {
        $userObjDataTemp = $request->session()->get('userObjData');
        if (isset($userObjDataTemp)) {
            $response['success'] = 1;
            $response['message'] = 'Sessão do usuário retornada';
            $response['userObjData'] = $userObjDataTemp;
            return $response;
        } else {
            $response['success'] = 0;
            $response['message'] = 'Sessão finalizada';
            return $response;
        }
    }

    public function cleanUserSession(Request $request) {

        $request->session()->forget('userObjData');

        $response['success'] = 1;
        $response['message'] = 'Sessão expirada';
        return $response;

    }
```

My routes from web.php

```
Route::post('/user/store/usersession', 'UserController@storeUserSession');
Route::get('/user/get/usersession', 'UserController@getUserSession');
Route::get('/user/clean/usersession', 'UserController@cleanUserSession');
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are your routes for these? If they are being passed through the 'api' middleware, and not 'web' middleware, sessions do not work.

Comment: Hi @DarrylE.Clarke, all my routes are web, my Laravel is 6.6 and in search of the web I see this session.gc_maxlifetime on php.ini, I really need to change this or Laravel by default override it? Just an observation my session work fine just the life_time that is not honored